# Problemas con HashMap

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8

Alguno me daría una mano con estos 3 métodos ...

```
    class Vacuna{
        String nombre;
        int cantidad
        }
    
    class Main{
        HashMap<Vacuna,Fecha> almacenamientoVacunas;
```

Si se ingresa de nuevo una vacuna con el mismo nombre la cantidad se debe sumar al stock existente.

```
    public void ingresarVacunas(String nombreVacuna, int cantidad, Fecha fechaIngreso) {

    }
```

Total de vacunas:

```
    public int vacunasDisponibles() {
        
    }
```

Total de vacunas que coincida con el nombre de vacuna especificado:

```
    public int vacunasDisponibles(String nombreVacuna) {
        
    }
```

Comment: Debes de mostrar un codigo que demuestre que lo has intentado mínimamente, las preguntas que piden hacer un ejercicio desde 0 no son bien recibidas.

Comment: El tema es que no me sale , osea, el hasmap<vacuna,fecha> (clave, valor)  no lo entenderia mucho cuando hay dos tipos en el, osea, nose  el como comparar siquiera los nombres o cantidades que tiene una vacuna dentro de   ingresarVacuna()

Comment: a lo que voy es que, si tengo como clave la vacuna, como es q entro y pregunto por el nombre y si coincide cuantas cantidades de vacunas tiene como para sumarle otras siend, eso es lo q no tengo idea

Answer (score 0):

El HashMap es como un diccionario por así decirlo, porque puedes guardar objetos asociados a una clave.Entinces, tus vacunas se deberían guardar en el HashMap asociadas al nombre.

```
     HasshMap<String,Vacuna> almacVacunas;
```

En la línea de arriba hemos declarado la variable que guardara los objetos vacunas asociados a su nombre. Por eso se define como <String,Vacuna>. En String ponemos el nombre.

Para guardar una vacuna utilizamos:

```
  public void ingresarVacunas(String nombreVacuna, int cantidad, Fecha fechaIngreso) {
        // Buscamos en nuestro mapa si la vacuna existe

          Vacuna v = almacVacunas.get(nombreVacuna);
         // Si existe, entonces en v tenemos el Objeto vacuna y actualizamos los datos:

          If(v!=null) {
                // Sumamos la cantidad
                v.cantidad+=cantidad;
           }
           else{
            // La vacuna no existe entonces creamos el objeto y lo agregamos al mapa
              v = new Vacuna();
             v.nom...  // completas las asignaciones
              v.cantida.. 
              v.fecha=...
            // Lo ponemos en nuestro mapa
              almacVacunas.put(v.nombreVacuna,v);

          }

   }
```

Con lo anterior ya sabes cómo estaré y colocar objetos del mapa.

Agrega la fecha a la clase  vacuna

Por otro lado si quieres mantener la lista de las vacunas por nombre, entonces tú mapa debería ser HashMap<String,List< Vacuna >> y guardar cada vacuna en la lista.